# One Edit Button for Bootstrab Datatable

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a table (Datatable) filled with records, I do not need to showing `Edit` button in each row, I want the user to select row and then press edit button (below the tabel) to open a bootstrap modal filled with selected row data.

Can I do that and How ?

I'm trying to pass the selected row ID to Bootstrap Modal, Let say I have an variable with selected record `ID`, and the record `ID` number was 25:

```
$id= 25;
```

and here is the `edit button`:

```
<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#EditRecordModal<?php echo $id;?>" type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-sm'>Edit</button>
```

The Modal Id will be:

```
<div id="EditRecordModal<?php echo $id;?>" class="modal fade">
```

Not working :(

Comment: you can store record id in `data` attribute and achieve it.

Comment: @DevsiOdedra Can you tell me how?

Comment: you are using checkbox for selection of row, so give that check box and `data-id` store your primary id in that data-id, then you can match id and get data and fill in popup.

Comment: I failed with that, If you can please put some guiding code

Comment: show your code here or in snippest so i can help.

Comment: @DevsiOdedra I update my questions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194810/discussion-between-devsi-odedra-and-abdulsalam-elsharif).

Answer (score 0):

You can enable multi select option in Datatable and use data attr to get the values and make another Datatable

Something like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();

    $('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    } );

    $('#button').click( function () {
        alert( table.rows('.selected').data().length +' row(s) selected' );
    } );
} );
```

More [detail here](https://datatables.net/examples/api/select_row.html)

or can try even [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/bindrid/sc0bo122/6/)